# Как получить массив отмеченных чекбоксом элементов?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Отмечаем все посты чекбоксами:

```
<input ng-click="selectAllPosts()" class="select-all-posts" type="checkbox"><label class="select-all-posts">{{ selectedText }}</label>
```

Выводим все посты:

```
        <div class="flagged-post" data-ng-repeat="post in posts" >
                <input ng-checked="post.checked" ng-model="post.checked" type="checkbox" class="select-post">
```

```
                    $scope.selectedText = 'Select All Posts';
                $scope.isAll = false;
                $scope.selectAllPosts = function() {

                    if($scope.isAll === false) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){
                            post.checked = true;

                        });
                        $scope.isAll = true;
                        $scope.selectedText = 'Deselect All Posts';
                    } else {
                        angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(post){
                            post.checked = false;

                        });
                        $scope.isAll = false;
                        $scope.selectedText = 'Select All Posts';
                    }
                };


                $scope.getFullName = function( post ) {
                    post.checked = false;
                };

                $scope.selectedPostsFilter = function () {
                    return $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {checked: true});
                };
```

Как получит массив выбраных объектов для того чтобы пройтись дальше forEach'ом?

```
                    $scope.removeSelectedPosts = function () {
                    angular.forEach(selectedObj, function(post) {
                        //что-то делаем
                                });
                };
```

Comment: функция _selectedPostsFilter_ как раз и возвращает все выбранные посты

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять на true/false

```
   document.getElementById('индекс').checked
```

и собирать это в массив с помощью `array.push`
ну а дальше уже дело техники (foreach'а)

Answer (score -1):

Пологою, примерно так:

```
var box_id='id_form';//id формы, или чего там у тебя есть, в чем эти чекбоксы находятся 
var ins = document.getElementById(box_id).getElementsByTagName('input');//Все input'ы в форме
var cheks_obj = [];//Сюда будем записывать нашу выборку
for(var i in ins){
   /* Если это - чекбокс и он отмечен - загоняем в массив*/
   if(ins[i].type=="checkbox"&&ins[i].checked){cheks_obj.push(ins[i]);}
}
```